Graph $G$ with $n$ vertices is connected AND has diameter at most 2 if $\Delta$(G) + $\delta(G) \geq n-1$
I was going through Chartrand and Zhang's "Introduction to Graph Theory" and found exercise 2.12 as stated in the title. I have what I think is a proof for the statement but it only shows that the diameter of the graph is at most $4$. Here's a brief sketch of my argument; my question is whether or not the statement in the title is even true and if so, whether my proof of the statement with the relaxed diameter condition is correct, then how I can modify it to prove the title statement.
Proof (of modified statement):
Let $x$ be a vertex in graph $G$ with $\deg(x) = \Delta(G)$ and $y$ be a vertex with $\deg(y) = \delta(G)$. Then assume $x$ and $y$ are non-adjacent. Also assume $x \neq y$.
Since $\deg(x) + \deg(y) \geq n-1$ and they are non-adjacent and distinct, we know (by the pigeonhole principle) that $x$ and $y$ share at least one neighbor. In fact, $x$ and $u$ share at least one neighbor for any vertex $u \in V(G)$ since the inequality holds for any vertex not equal to $y$ as well. Thus, every vertex $u$ in the graph is either adjacent to $x$ or there is a $u-x$ path of length $2$. Therefore, $G$ is connected and has diameter at most $4$ since the longest distance between any two vertices in the graph is at most $4$, with two disjoint paths of length $2$ through $x$.
If $x$ and $y$ are adjacent, the argument can still be applied for any vertex $u$ and $x$ and you can always show that when $u$ and $x$ are non-adjacent, they must share a common vertex.
If $x = y$ then we have $\Delta(G) = \delta(G)$ so $\delta(G) + \delta(G) \geq n-1$ therefore $\delta(G) \geq \frac{n-1}{2}$, and it is known that such a graph must be connected with diameter at most $2$ by the same argument pigeonhole principle argument provided above. This concludes all cases.
Question: How do we guarantee that the diameter is at most $2$? This seems like a very strong requirement
Edit: Thanks to Misha Lavrov, I discovered that this book is out of date and the newest edition which corrects the mistake changed its title from "Introduction to Graph Theory" to "A First Course in Graph Theory". The mistake was simply the authors realizing that "diameter at most 2" is too strong of a statement and "diameter at most 4" is correct.

The path graph $P_4$ has $n=4$, $\Delta=2$ and $\delta=1$, and the diameter is $3$. The union of two $4$-cycles with one shared vertex has $n=7$, $\Delta=4$, and $\delta=2$, and the diameter is $4$. Maybe they meant to say radius at most $2$?

@user14111 Thank you for providing the examples. I do think they either meant diameter at most 4 or radius at most 2. If for every pair of non-adjacent vertices in a graph you have that degree sum inequality, then you have a connected graph of diameter 2, but without this very strong condition, it seems like a diameter of at most 2 would be too hard to achieve. I've found no information in the errata.

You should communicate this correction to the authors, I'm sure they will be grateful to have it.

Why are you showing the diameter is anything?  Diameter at most 2 seems to be an assumption, not a conclusion.

@dbal The question asks to prove this fact, along with proving such a graph is connected. It's not an assumption.

@PerpetuallyConfused The awkward syntax of your title makes it look like the exercise is to prove that "$G$ is connected" if "$\Delta+\delta\ge n-1$ and diameter at least $2$".

I checked my copy of Chartrand and Zhang's First Course in Graph Theory. (To explain the title: the bibliographical note in this book calls it a "revised and corrected republication of Introduction to Graph Theory".) In this book, exercise 2.12 says:

Prove that if $G$ is a graph of order $n$ such that $\Delta(G) + \delta(G) \ge n-1$, then $G$ is connected and $\operatorname{diam}(G) \le 4$. Show that the bound $n-1$ is sharp.

It appears, then, that at some point the authors discovered that these hypotheses are not strong enough to prove diameter $2$.
In fact, for all $n \ge 7$, there is a graph with this property that has diameter exactly $4$. To achieve this:

start with a path of length $4$: $(x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$.
add a vertex $y$ which is a copy of $x_1$: it also has neighbors $x_0$ and $x_2$.
add $n-6$ vertices $z_1, \dots, z_{n-6}$ which are copies of $x_3$: they also have neighbors $x_2$ and $x_4$.

Then $\deg(x_2) = n-3$ (the only non-neighbors of $x_2$ are $x_0$ and $x_4$) while $\deg(x_4) = n-5$ and all other vertices have degree $2$. Therefore, for $n \ge 7$, $\Delta(G)=n-3$ and $\delta(G)=2$: the hypotheses hold. However, the distance between $x_0$ and $x_4$ in this graph is $4$: the path we started with is an $x_0 - x_4$ path of length $4$, and the vertices we add later don't make the path any shorter.

Thank you for the response. I did not know that "A First Course in Graph Theory" is an edited, republished version of "Introduction to Graph Theory" by the same authors. I would have checked online discussion on this book for more information about this question.
